# List of object types on SE API v2.0+

Tags: support, api-v2.1

Beware: The API is Huge!!

Below is the list of all the "types" of objects returned by the API v2.0+ :-
<sub>Note: v2.1 specific types are noted in a seperate box</sub>

```
Type               | Field                        | Field Type
-------------------+------------------------------+----------------------
answers            | answer_id                    | int, refers to an answer
                   | body                         | str (2)
                   | comments                     | array(comments)
                   | community_owned_date         | date (1)
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | down_vote_count              | int
                   | is_accepted                  | bool
                   | last_activity_date           | date
                   | last_edit_date               | date (1)
                   | link                         | str (2)
                   | locked_date                  | date (1)
                   | owner                        | shallow_user (1)
                   | question_id                  | int, refers to a question
                   | score                        | int
                   | title                        | str
                   | up_vote_count                | int
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
question           | accepted_answer_id           | int  (1)
                   | answer_count                 | int
                   | answers                      | array(answers)
                   | body                         | str (2)
                   | bounty_amount                | int  (1)
                   | bounty_closes_date           | date (1)
                   | closed_date                  | date (1)
                   | closed_reason                | str  (1)
                   | comments                     | array(comments)
                   | community_owned_date         | date (1)
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | down_vote_count              | int
                   | favorite_count               | int
                   | is_answered                  | bool
                   | last_activity_date           | date
                   | last_edit_date               | date (1)
                   | link                         | str (2)
                   | locked_date                  | date (1)
                   | migrated_from                | migration_info (1)
                   | migrated_to                  | migration_info (1)
                   | owner                        | shallow_user (1)
                   | protected_date               | date (1)
                   | question_id                  | int, refers to a question
                   | score                        | int
                   | tags                         | array(strs)
                   | title                        | str
                   | up_vote_count                | int
                   | view_count                   | int
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
access_token       | access_token                 | str
                   | account_id                   | int
                   | expires_on_date              | date (1)
                   | scope                        | array(strs)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
answer             | answer_id                    | int, refers to an answer
                   | body                         | str (2)
                   | comments                     | array(comments)
                   | community_owned_date         | date (1)
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | down_vote_count              | int
                   | is_accepted                  | bool
                   | last_activity_date           | date
                   | last_edit_date               | date (1)
                   | link                         | str (2)
                   | locked_date                  | date (1)
                   | owner                        | shallow_user (1)
                   | question_id                  | int, refers to a question
                   | score                        | int
                   | title                        | str
                   | up_vote_count                | int
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
badge              | award_count                  | int
                   | badge_id                     | int, refers to a badge
                   | badge_type                   | one of named, or tag_based
                   | description                  | str (2)
                   | link                         | str (2)
                   | name                         | str
                   | rank                         | one of gold, silver, or bronze
                   | user                         | shallow_user (1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
comment            | body                         | str (2)
                   | comment_id                   | int, refers to a comment
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | edited                       | bool
                   | link                         | str (2)
                   | owner                        | shallow_user (1)
                   | post_id                      | int, refers to a post
                   | post_type                    | one of question, or answer
                   | reply_to_user                | shallow_user (1)
                   | score                        | int
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
error              | description                  | str
                   | error_id                     | int, refers to an error
                   | error_name                   | str
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
event              | creation_date                | date
                   | event_id                     | the id of the object (answer, comment, question, or user) the event describes
                   | event_type                   | one of question_posted, answer_posted, comment_posted, post_edited, or user_created
                   | excerpt                      | str (2)
                   | link                         | str (2)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
filter             | filter                       | str
                   | filter_type                  | one of safe, unsafe, or invalid
                   | included_fields              | array(strs)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
inbox_item         | answer_id                    | int, refers to an answer (1)
                   | body                         | str (2)
                   | comment_id                   | int, refers to a comment (1)
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | is_unread                    | bool
                   | item_type                    | one of comment, chat_message, new_answer, careers_message, careers_invitations, meta_question, post_notice, or moderator_message
                   | link                         | str (2)
                   | question_id                  | int, refers to a question (1)
                   | site                         | site (1)
                   | title                        | str
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
info               | answers_per_minute           | decimal
                   | api_revision                 | str
                   | badges_per_minute            | decimal
                   | new_active_users             | int
                   | questions_per_minute         | decimal
                   | site                         | site
                   | total_accepted               | int
                   | total_answers                | int
                   | total_badges                 | int
                   | total_comments               | int
                   | total_questions              | int
                   | total_unanswered             | int
                   | total_users                  | int
                   | total_votes                  | int
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
network_user       | account_id                   | int
                   | answer_count                 | int
                   | badge_counts                 | badge_count
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | last_access_date             | date
                   | question_count               | int
                   | reputation                   | int
                   | site_name                    | str
                   | site_url                     | str
                   | user_id                      | int, refers to a user
                   | user_type                    | one of unregistered, registered, moderator, or does_not_exist
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
user type          | about_me                     | str (2) (1)
                   | accept_rate                  | int  (1)
                   | account_id                   | int
                   | age                          | int  (1)
                   | answer_count                 | int
                   | badge_counts                 | badge_count
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | display_name                 | str
                   | down_vote_count              | int
                   | is_employee                  | bool
                   | last_access_date             | date
                   | last_modified_date           | date (1)
                   | link                         | str (2)
                   | location                     | str  (1)
                   | profile_image                | str (2)
                   | question_count               | int
                   | reputation                   | int
                   | reputation_change_day        | int
                   | reputation_change_month      | int
                   | reputation_change_quarter    | int
                   | reputation_change_week       | int
                   | reputation_change_year       | int
                   | timed_penalty_date           | date (1)
                   | up_vote_count                | int
                   | user_id                      | int, refers to a user
                   | user_type                    | one of unregistered, registered, moderator, or does_not_exist
                   | view_count                   | int
                   | website_url                  | str (2) (1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
post               | body                         | str (2)
                   | comments                     | array(comments)
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | down_vote_count              | int
                   | last_activity_date           | date
                   | last_edit_date               | date (1)
                   | owner                        | shallow_user (1)
                   | post_id                      | int, refers to a post
                   | post_type                    | one of question, or answer
                   | score                        | int
                   | up_vote_count                | int
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
privilege          | description                  | str (2)
                   | reputation                   | int
                   | short_description            | str (2)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
question           | accepted_answer_id           | int  (1)
                   | answer_count                 | int
                   | answers                      | array(answers)
                   | body                         | str (2)
                   | bounty_amount                | int  (1)
                   | bounty_closes_date           | date (1)
                   | closed_date                  | date (1)
                   | closed_reason                | str  (1)
                   | comments                     | array(comments)
                   | community_owned_date         | date (1)
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | down_vote_count              | int
                   | favorite_count               | int
                   | is_answered                  | bool
                   | last_activity_date           | date
                   | last_edit_date               | date (1)
                   | link                         | str (2)
                   | locked_date                  | date (1)
                   | migrated_from                | migration_info (1)
                   | migrated_to                  | migration_info (1)
                   | owner                        | shallow_user (1)
                   | protected_date               | date (1)
                   | question_id                  | int, refers to a question
                   | score                        | int
                   | tags                         | array(strs)
                   | title                        | str
                   | up_vote_count                | int
                   | view_count                   | int
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
question_timeline  | comment_id                   | int, refers to a comment (1)
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | down_vote_count              | int  (1)
                   | owner                        | shallow_user (1)
                   | post_id                      | int, refers to a post (1)
                   | question_id                  | int, refers to a question
                   | revision_guid                | str  (1)
                   | timeline_type                | one of question, answer, comment, unaccepted_answer, accepted_answer, vote_aggregate, revision, or post_state_changed
                   | up_vote_count                | int  (1)
                   | user                         | shallow_user (1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
reputation         | link                         | str (2)
                   | on_date                      | date
                   | post_id                      | int, refers to a post
                   | post_type                    | one of question, or answer
                   | reputation_change            | int
                   | title                        | str
                   | user_id                      | int, refers to a user
                   | vote_type                    | one of accepts, up_votes, down_votes, bounties_offered, bounties_won, spam, or suggested_edits
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
reputation_history | creation_date                | date
                   | post_id                      | int, refers to a post (1)
                   | reputation_change            | int
                   | reputation_history_type      | one of asker_accepts_answer, asker_unaccept_answer, answer_accepted, answer_unaccepted, voter_downvotes, voter_undownvotes, post_downvoted, post_undownvoted, post_upvoted, post_unupvoted, suggested_edit_approval_received, post_flagged_as_spam, post_flagged_as_offensive, bounty_given, bounty_earned, bounty_cancelled, post_deleted, post_undeleted, association_bonus, arbitrary_reputation_change, vote_fraud_reversal, post_migrated, or user_deleted
                   | user_id                      | int, refers to a user
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
revision           | body                         | str (2) (1)
                   | comment                      | str
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | is_rollback                  | bool
                   | last_body                    | str (2) (1)
                   | last_tags                    | array(strs)
                   | last_title                   | str  (1)
                   | post_id                      | int, refers to a post
                   | post_type                    | one of question, or answer
                   | revision_guid                | str
                   | revision_number              | int
                   | revision_type                | one of single_user, or vote_based
                   | set_community_wiki           | bool
                   | tags                         | array(strs)
                   | title                        | str  (1)
                   | user                         | shallow_user
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
site               | aliases                      | array(strs)
                   | api_site_parameter           | str
                   | audience                     | str
                   | closed_beta_date             | date (1)
                   | favicon_url                  | str
                   | icon_url                     | str
                   | launch_date                  | date
                   | logo_url                     | str
                   | markdown_extensions          | array('MathJax',)
                   | name                         | str
                   | open_beta_date               | date (1)
                   | related_sites                | array(related_sites)
                   | site_state                   | one of normal, closed_beta, open_beta, or linked_meta
                   | site_type                    | one of main_site or meta_site, but new options may be added.
                   | site_url                     | str
                   | styling                      | styling
                   | twitter_account              | str  (1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
suggested_edit     | approval_date                | date (1)
                   | body                         | str (2) (1)
                   | comment                      | str
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | post_id                      | int, refers to a post
                   | post_type                    | one of question, or answer
                   | proposing_user               | shallow_user (1)
                   | rejection_date               | date (1)
                   | suggested_edit_id            | int, refers to a suggested_edit
                   | tags                         | array(strs)
                   | title                        | str  (1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
tag                | count                        | int
                   | has_synonyms                 | bool
                   | is_moderator_only            | bool
                   | is_required                  | bool
                   | last_activity_date           | date (1)
                   | name                         | str
                   | user_id                      | int, refers to a user (1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
tag_score          | post_count                   | int
                   | score                        | int
                   | user                         | shallow_user
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
tag_synonym        | applied_count                | int
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | from_tag                     | str
                   | last_applied_date            | date (1)
                   | to_tag                       | str
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
tag_wiki           | body                         | str (2) (1)
                   | body_last_edit_date          | date (1)
                   | excerpt                      | str  (1)
                   | excerpt_last_edit_date       | date (1)
                   | last_body_editor             | shallow_user (1)
                   | last_excerpt_editor          | shallow_user (1)
                   | tag_name                     | str
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
top_tag            | answer_count                 | int
                   | answer_score                 | int
                   | question_count               | int
                   | question_score               | int
                   | tag_name                     | str (2)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
user               | about_me                     | str (2) (1)
                   | accept_rate                  | int  (1)
                   | account_id                   | int
                   | age                          | int  (1)
                   | answer_count                 | int
                   | badge_counts                 | badge_count
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | display_name                 | str
                   | down_vote_count              | int
                   | is_employee                  | bool
                   | last_access_date             | date
                   | last_modified_date           | date (1)
                   | link                         | str (2)
                   | location                     | str  (1)
                   | profile_image                | str (2)
                   | question_count               | int
                   | reputation                   | int
                   | reputation_change_day        | int
                   | reputation_change_month      | int
                   | reputation_change_quarter    | int
                   | reputation_change_week       | int
                   | reputation_change_year       | int
                   | timed_penalty_date           | date (1)
                   | up_vote_count                | int
                   | user_id                      | int, refers to a user
                   | user_type                    | one of unregistered, registered, moderator, or does_not_exist
                   | view_count                   | int
                   | website_url                  | str (2) (1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
user_timeline      | badge_id                     | int, refers to a badge (1)
                   | comment_id                   | int, refers to a comment (1)
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | detail                       | str (2) (1)
                   | link                         | str (2)
                   | post_id                      | int, refers to a post (1)
                   | post_type                    | one of question, or answer
                   | suggested_edit_id            | int, refers to a suggested_edit (1)
                   | timeline_type                | one of commented, asked, answered, badge, revision, accepted, reviewed, or suggested
                   | title                        | str  (1)
                   | user_id                      | int, refers to a user
```

**Member Types**
The following types are not returned directly by any method, but are found as members on other types.

```
Type               | Field                        | Field Type
-------------------+------------------------------+----------------------
badge_count        | bronze                       | int
                   | gold                         | int
                   | silver                       | int
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
migration_info     | on_date                      | date
                   | other_site                   | site
                   | question_id                  | int, refers to a question
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
related_site       | api_site_parameter           | str  (1)
                   | name                         | str
                   | relation                     | one of parent, meta, or chat, but new options may be added.
                   | site_url                     | str (2)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
shallow_user       | accept_rate                  | int  (1)
                   | display_name                 | str  (1)
                   | link                         | str (2) (1)
                   | profile_image                | str (2) (1)
                   | reputation                   | int  (1)
                   | user_id                      | int, refers to a user (1)
                   | user_type                    | one of unregistered, registered, moderator, or does_not_exist
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
styling            | link_color                   | str
                   | tag_background_color         | str
                   | tag_foreground_color         | str
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**v2.1 Specific fields**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
comment            | body_markdown                | str
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
notice             | body                         | str (2)
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | owner_user_id                | int
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
notification       | body                         | str (2)
                   | creation_date                | date
                   | is_unread                    | bool
                   | notification_type            | one of generic, profile_activity, bounty_expired, bounty_expires_in_one_day, badge_earned, bounty_expires_in_three_days, reputation_bonus, accounts_associated, new_privilege, post_migrated, moderator_message, registration_reminder, edit_suggested, or substantive_edit
                   | post_id                      | int, refers to a post (1)
                   | site                         | site
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
question           | close_vote_count             | int
                   | delete_vote_count            | int
                   | notice                       | notice
                   | reopen_vote_count            | int
                   | close_vote_count             | int
                   | delete_vote_count            | int
                   | notice                       | notice
                   | reopen_vote_count            | int
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
site               | high_resolution_icon_url     | str  (1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
answers            | tags                         | array(strs)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
account_merge      | merge_date                   | date
                   | new_account_id               | int
                   | old_account_id               | int
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
answer             | tags                         | array(strs)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
post               | link                         | str
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
top_tag            | user_id                      | int, refers to a user
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
write_permission   | can_add                      | bool
                   | can_delete                   | bool
                   | can_edit                     | bool
                   | max_daily_actions            | int
                   | min_seconds_between_actions  | int
                   | object_type                  | str
                   | user_id                      | int, refers to a user
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Key:
 `(1)`  : may be absent
 `(2)`  : unchanged in unsafe filters
 `int`  : integer
 `str`  : string
 `bool` : boolean
 `array(x)` : an array of x

Note: All this info has been extracted from Stack Exchange API Docs... by [this script](http://pastebin.com/HSArTuvM).

Answer (score 2):

Grouping the [API documentation by type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs?tab=type#docs) gives you the list of routes under the specific object type that they return, with a link describing the respective type. You should be able to determine the comprehensive list from that.

Comment: Thanks but I knew that already. I was simply working on it. :) It's done now. See my update...